# Array of unconstrained mutable type in Ada

Tags: arrays, types, ada

I am trying to make an array of unconstrained mutable type elements; but, as the element is unconstrained, I get this error: "unconstrained element type in array declaration".

Here is my square type declaration :

```
type C_square(size : bRange) is tagged record

private

type C_square(size : bRange) is tagged record
  bConstaint : uint8 := size; 
  coord : T_coord;            
  color : e_color := unknown; 
end record;
```

And here comes the error:

```
type C_board(size : bRange) is tagged limited private; 

type square_matrix is array (uint8 range <>, uint8 range <>) of C_square; -- here is the problem C_square is unconstrained

private
type C_board(size : bRange := MIN_SIZE) is tagged limited record
  bSize    : uint8 := size;
  square_m : square_matrix(1..size, 1..size);
end record;
```

Is there any solution that allow me to have an array of unconstrained mutable elements?

Comment: You maybe looking for an [_indefinite container_](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rat/html/Rat-8-5.html).

Comment: Perhaps giving a default for size will make a difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have an **array** of unconstrained elements.

Some alternatives:

- Use an indefinite vector.  (Good!)
- Create an array of access to your indefinite type.  (Bad!)